# I need to sum all the divisors of a number to work with amicable numbers

Tags: php

This is the function that i have made so far:

```
function divisor($number)
{
    echo "Divisors of number : $number<br>";
    for($i=1;$i<$number;$i++)
    {
        if ( ($number%$i)==0)
        {
            echo $i,',';
        }

    }
}
divisor("220");
```

This is the output of the function :

```
Divisors of number : 220<br>1,2,4,5,10,11,20,22,44,55,110,
```

The sum of the divisors will be 284 , that means that number 220 and 284 are amicable numbers

I wan't to sum all the divisors of the number that i enter in the function, How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a minor adjustment in your function. Store all the divisors in an array. To print a comma-separated list of divisors, use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode). To calculate the sum of the values in the array, use [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/array_sum). Pretty simple.

Here's the rewritten function:

```
function divisor($number)
{
    $divisors = array(); // Initialize empty array
    for ($i = 1; $i < $number; $i++)
    {
        if (($number % $i) == 0)
        {
            $divisors[] = $i;
        }
    }
    echo "Divisors of number: " . implode(', ', $divisors) . "<br />";
    echo "Total sum: " . array_sum($divisors) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Divisors of number: 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55, 110
Total sum: 284
```

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to simply use a variable ($count) starting with 0 and then add $i each time ($number % $i) is true? Is it faster using an array?

Comment: @briosheje: I think `array_sum()` would likely be faster as it's implemented in C. But performance difference, if any, should be minuscule and should be ignored.

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks for the explanation, I was just wondering why you were using an array for such an easy job :)

Comment: @briosheje: An array allows you to keep the individual numbers for printing or other purposes now or later.  `$sum += $number;` would easily get you the sum but not allow you to have the individual divisors.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: Fine, but my wonder was, at that point, what was faster :)

Answer (score 0):

A faster solution that works as well:

```
<?php

function get_div_sum($n)
{
    for ($j = 1, $s = 0; $j <= $n; $j++)
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++)
            if (!($j % $i))
                $s += $i;

    return $s;
}
```